# SLURM: how to disable automatic job cleanup when one PE crashes

Tags: mpi, openmpi, slurm

I distribute OpenMPI-based application using SLURM launcher `srun`. When one the process crashes, I would like to detect that in the other PEs and to do some actions. I am aware of the fact that OpenMPI does not have fault-tolerance, but still I need to perform a graceful exit in other PEs.

To do this, every PE has to be able:

1. To continue running despite the crash of another PE.
2. To detect that one of the PEs crashed.

Currently I'm focusing on the first task. According to the manual, [srun has --no-kill flag](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html). However, it does not seem to work for me. I see the following log messages:

```
srun: error: node0: task 0: Aborted    // this is where I crash the PE deliberately
slurmstepd: error: node0: [0] pmixp_client_v2.c:210 [_errhandler] mpi/pmix: ERROR: Error handler invoked: status = -25: Interrupted system call (4)
srun: Jb step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error: ***STEP 12123.0 ON node0 CANCELLED AT 2020-12-02 ***
srun: error: node0: task 1: Killed    // WHY?!
```

Why does it happen? Is there any other relevant flag or environment variable, or any configuration option that might help?

To reproduce the problem, one can use the following program (it uses Boost.MPI for brevity, but has the same effect without Boost as well):

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>

int main() {
  using namespace boost::mpi;
  environment env;
  communicator comm;
  comm.barrier();
  if (comm.rank() == 0) {
    throw 0;
  }
  while (true) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation that you linked, the `--no-kill` flag only affects the behaviour in case of node failure.

In your case you should be using the `--kill-on-bad-exit=0` option that will prevent the rest of the tasks to be killed if one of them exits with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Tried this one as well - the same result.

Comment: BTW, exiting with non-zero code does not make SLURM kill all the PEs. A crash - does.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your behaviour. For me slurm doesn't kill the remaining task, but the task hangs during the MPI_Finalize. What version of Slurm and OpenMPI are you using?

Comment: `srun --version`: 19.05.5;    `mpirun --version`: 4.0.2a1.   (To crash a PE I throw C++ exception.)

Comment: I added a trivial reproducer.

Comment: Look at the source code: `grep -A3 orte_enable_recovery orte/mca/plm/slurm/plm_slurm_module.c
    if (!orte_enable_recovery) {
        /* kill the job if any orteds die */
        opal_argv_append(&argc, &argv, "--kill-on-bad-exit");` 
It would seem ompi/oshmem must be run with --enable_recovry for this to work well with slurm

Comment: @Dani_l  `--enable-recovery` is `openmpi` flag, but I run `srun`.

Comment: @IgorR. did you figure it out

Comment: @JulesG.M. no, as far as I remember.